# Parallel processing of stdin lines with multiprocess

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a basic script that reads in a a csv file line by line, does some basic processing of each line and using this decides if it wants to keep the line or not. If it keeps it, it goes into a buffer array which is then written later on (or dealt with appropriately with chunking if the file will not fit in to RAM, but more on that later). I was advised that because of the magic of HDDs i would benefit greatly from a write-buffer rather than just looping each line through directly.

I am attempting to see if I can speed this up by doing the processing of the line on a different process to the stdin reading the line. It is clear that the script is i/o speed bound so i want that to be running as much as possible, not waiting for cpu stuff.

To try this i set up 2 processes using pipes to move the lines from one to the other. This seems to work, however is an order of magnitude slower than if i just did everything in a single loop over the lines being fed in.

**Basic implement snippet**

```
outStream = open("updated.csv",'w')
outputBuffer = []
for line in sys.stdin:  
    row = line.strip()
    index = parseRow(row) # CPU-bound process

    if index not in mainList:
        outputBuffer.append(row)

    # some test to see if memory is filling up, if so dump it and reset buffer, just here to show logic atm
    if(getMem()>60):
        writeBuffer(outputBuffer, outStream)
        outputBuffer = []

# make sure last batch is written out
if outputBuffer != []:
    writeBuffer(outputBuffer, outStream)
outStream.close()
```

**Attempt at parallel solution**

```
def reader( lineConn, fileno ):
    for line in os.fdopen(fileno):
        lineConn.send(line)
    lineConn.send("end")

def parser( lineConn ):
    outputBuffer = []
    outStream = open("updated.csv",'w')
    while 1:
        line = lineConn.recv()
        if(line == "end"):
            break
        row = line.strip()
        index = parseRow(row)

        if index not in mainList:
            outputBuffer.append(row)

    writeBuffer(outputBuffer, outStream)

############ main
outputBuffer = []

lineRead, lineParse = Pipe()

io = sys.stdin.fileno() 
p1 = Process(target=reader, args=(lineRead,io))
p2 = Process(target=parser, args=(lineParse,)) 

p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

I suspect it has something to do with the send being slower than the receive, but i also put in a wait timer on the parsing end (i.e. if poll() was false then just hang tight for a bit) but even so the moment i add in the send(line) stuff it grinds to a halt, presumably because i don't understand enough about how it all works.

I had grand plans for making sure that the reading was paused when the writing needed to be done, i.e. file didn't fit in RAM, but got stuck way before that.

As an aside, part of the reason the parsing is low is because i need to hunt down the comma part of the csv (just 2 col) to dig out the index, which means reading the line to get the line and then reading it again to find the comma and grab the integer before it - is there a way to somehow get the stdin to deal with some of this? i.e. read the line and also return the position of the first comma you found?

**Important edit**
Actually just realised the task requires the output to be sent to stdout not directly written to file, so does this mean i don't need to buffer because the HDD i/o is only on one end?

Comment: Do the lines have to come out in the same order as they are read? How long does the entire process take? How many lines is the file you are processing? How many bytes is the file?

Comment: Ah yes I forgot this part: yes the new file needs to maintain the ordering, so I didn't table with much parallel mapping stuff, although possibly this would still help? Also, at first glance it seemed I couldn't do this easily with pool, but happy to be proven wrong.